# Adding POST variables to Go test http Request

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, http-post

I am trying to add form variables to a Go http request.

Here's how my Go test looks:

```
func sample_test(t *testing.T) {
    handler := &my_listener_class{}
    reader := strings.NewReader("number=2")
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/my_url", reader)
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler.function_to_test(w, req)
    if w.Code != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Home page didn't return %v", http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

The issue is that the form data never gets passed on to the function I need to test.

The other relevant function is:

```
func (listener *my_listener_class) function_to_test(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

I am using Go version go1.3.3 darwin/amd64.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a `Content-Type` header to the request so the handler will know how to treat the POST body data:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/my_url", reader) //BTW check for error
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: I tried that, and...  kaboom! (ran go test)

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x1271d0]

Comment: @mirage that's probably a problem in your handler, you're not giving enough context to see what it is. but at least we know my answer was correct for your specific question.

Comment: yes, that worked. I had some other issues. Fixed those now. thanks a lot.